# Js promise for calculator

Tags: javascript, testing, promise, mocha.js, calculator

I have a simple calculator function that I wrote for a coding challenge. Now I'm having trouble with an additional `calculate` function that should return a promise.

```
class Calculator{
    constructor(){
        this[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'Calculator'; 
    } 
    add(a, b) {
        return a + b; 
    } 
    subtract(a, b) {
        return a - b; 
    }  
    multiply(a, b) {
        return a * b;
    } 
    divide(a, b) {
        if(b === 0){ 
            return NaN;
        }
        return a / b; 
    }
    toString(){
        return "Calculator";
    }
    calculate(...args) {
        var result = 0;
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            setTimeout(function() {
                if(result === NaN) {
                   reject(NaN);
                } else {
                   resolve(result);
                }
            }, 1000);
        });
    }
}
```

And here are the tests that the promise needs to meet:

```
describe( "Calculator.calculate", function(){
  let calculator;

  beforeEach( function(){
    calculator = new Calculator();
  } );
  
  it( "returns a promise", function( done ){
    const
      callDone = () => done(),
      calculating = calculator.calculate( () => void 0 );
    expect( calculating ).to.be.instanceOf( Promise );
    calculating.then( callDone ).catch( callDone );
  } );
     
  it( "resolves with the result when the calculation succeeds", function( done ){
    const calculating = calculator.calculate( function(){
      expect( this ).to.equal( calculator );
      let result = 0;
      result += this.add( 1, 2 );
      result += this.add( 3, 4 );
      return result;
    } );
    calculating
      .then( function( result ){
        expect( result ).to.equal( 10 );
        done();
      } )
      .catch( () => done() );
  } );
  
  it( "rejects with NaN when the calculation fails", function( done ){
    const calculating = calculator.calculate();
    calculating.catch( function( result ){
      expect( result ).to.be.NaN;
      done();
    } );
  } );
} );
```

The above `calculate` function I wrote only passes the first test and none of the other. I fear I'm going about it all wrong. How can I make it work?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but your promise doesn't seem to have any issues.

Comment: What's the point of using promises for a calculator?

Comment: my calculate function needs to satisfy the tests in the above describe block. I'd tell you what error it throws but unfortunately what im working in for this doesnt give me error info.

Comment: @zer00ne your guess is as good as mine, but i need to get this done regardless lol. Any help is very appreciated. thanks

Comment: you need to put the value you want returned in the parenthesis of either the resolve or reject. so your resolve should probably be `resolve(result);` and your reject maybe `reject(NaN);` something like that

Comment: `NaN` does not equal anything, even itself. You must use `isNaN(value)` to check for it. See [MDN's article on Testing against NaN for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN#testing_against_nan).

Comment: @Portal

Took your advice and got some success, but the third test is still failing. I edited my post to reflect the changes. any other thoughts?

Comment: And please, the word is "I'm", not "im".

Comment: @dezratt since the test case is using a catch, maybe you need to restructure your calculate function to use a try catch rather than if else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks on your attempt:

- The requirements do not suggest that you need to *delay* a result using `setTimeout`.
- There is no need for `...args` as parameter list for `calculate`. It will only get one argument, and it should be a function.
- The `result` variable is never set to anything else than 0. It would need to be the result by calling the callback function (the argument passed to `calculate`).
- `resolve` should be called with the result as argument.
- `reject` should be called with `NaN` as argument
- There is no specification that when the result is `NaN`, the promise should be rejected. The opposite is true: when the promise rejects (because of an error) it should reject with NaN as reason. The last test in the test sequence, passes no argument to `calculate`, which would lead to an error while `calculate` tries to execute an argument that is undefined. And then it should return a rejected promise.

We can avoid calling the Promise constructor by declaring the method as `async`. Here is an implementation that passes those tests:

```
    async calculate(f) {
        try {   
            return f.call(this);
        } catch {
            throw NaN;
        }
    }
```

Comment: so i edited the above initial calculator to adhere to some of your advice

and I got this

Calculator.calculate
returns a promise1002ms‣

resolves with the result when the calculation succeeds1015ms‣

rejects with NaN when the calculation fails‣
Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

Comment: I don't understand how you get times of over 1000ms. This looks like you still ran code with your `setTimeout` which indeed has 1000ms as delay argument.

Comment: I edited it to reflect the removal of the timeout. Nevertheless the error remains for whatever reason

Comment: What did you edit? Are you testing my code or yours? My code does not have delays of 1000ms like your output shows. Please clarify?

Comment: I edited the post to reflect changes I made. See above code. Its my calculate function thats been edited per your suggestions. The error is there too

Comment: Please don't update the question with information from my answer. That is not how this works. Now my mention of `setTimeout` looks stupid. I think I will move on to do something else. Sorry. Also, please test *my* code, not your code with the `setTimeout` removed.

Comment: your code works. Sorry I wanted to make what I wrote work instead of just taking yours. Thanks though!